# How to use pdfjs in a google cloud function to accept a pdf read from Dropbox as a fileBinary?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, pdf.js, dropbox-sdk-js

### Context

I am using Dropbox and PDFJs library inside a Google Cloud Function

### What I'm doing

Inside my `functions` folder i run

```
npm i --save pdfjs-dist
```

Then I download a pdf content from dropbox (this works)

```
exports.readAProgram = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
    var dbx = new Dropbox.Dropbox({ accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN });
    dbx.filesDownload({ path: "/full/path/20220702.pdf" })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('response', response)
            res.json(response.result.fileBinary);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // console.error(error);
            res.json({"error-1": error})
        });
});
```

I got this

[image]

Formatted is this

[image]

### Note

I do not known what exactly is a `fileBinary` because

- in the official doc (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download) I cannot see the fileBinary
- in the official example of a download they are using a diffent method (https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/main/examples/javascript/download/index.html)

### Next step: pass data to `PDF.js.getDocument`

I'm looking at the sourcecode, because obviously official api doc is useless.

See here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L232

The `getDocument` function accepts

```
string|URL|TypedArray|PDFDataRangeTransport|DocumentInitParameters
```

### Question

How can I convert my Dropbox `fileBinary` structure into something accettable from `PDFJS.getDocument` ?

### I tried

```
dbx.filesDownload({ path: "/full/path/20220702.pdf" })
    .then(function(response) {

        var loadingTask = PDFJS.getDocument(response.result.fileBinary)
            .then(function(pdf) {
                console.log ("OK !!!!")
                res.json(response.result.fileBinary);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log ("error)
                res.json({"error_2": error})
            });
```

But I got this on console

```
>  C:\laragon\www\test-pdf-dropbox\functions\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build\pdf.js:2240
>        data: structuredClone(obj, transfers)
>              ^
>  
>  ReferenceError: structuredClone is not defined
>      at LoopbackPort.postMessage (C:\laragon\www\test-pdf-dropbox\functions\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build\pdf.js:2240:13)
>      at MessageHandler.sendWithPromise (C:\laragon\www\test-pdf-dropbox\functions\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build\pdf.js:8555:19)
>      at _fetchDocument (C:\laragon\www\test-pdf-dropbox\functions\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build\pdf.js:1356:48)
>      at C:\laragon\www\test-pdf-dropbox\functions\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build\pdf.js:1302:29
>      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved

### First: use legacy dist of PDFJS

instead of using

```
const PDFJS = require("pdfjs-dist");
```

I do now

```
const PDFJS = require("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js");
```

the npm package is the same, `pdfjs-dist`

### Then: using PDFJS in this way

```
var pdf =  PDFJS.getDocument(new Uint8Array(response.result.fileBinary)).promise
            .then(function(pdf) {
                console.log ("Letto il PDF !!!!", pdf)
                res.json({done: true})
            })
```

Note

- fileBinary can be passed to PDFJS using `new Uint8Array`
- i appended `.promise` before of `.then`

Comment: OH. MY. F**king .... `require("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js");` .... How the fkcu did you figure that out?  I inherited this piece of code that uses pdfjs-dist, but it was kind of commented - I am guessing that the original developer couldn't figure out where the "undefined" error was coming from.  I've been toiling away line by line by line trying to figure out why none of the documented examples work.  And here it is.  some obscure require expression.  OMFG.  Thank you @realtebo for publishing this.

Comment: I read all the .js of pdfjs until I discovered a js compiled as native module instead of something requiring external loaders or bundlers to work. 
A lot of try-fail-try-fail --- try-work